# SeekBar is null?

Tags: android

Im doing the normal findViewById yet for some reason my app crashes due to SeekBar having a null value. It says

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SeekBar.setMax(int)' on a null object reference"

```
public class SettingsScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


@Bind(R.id.workText)
TextView work;
@Bind(R.id.restText)
TextView rest;
@Bind(R.id.workSeekBar)
SeekBar workBar;
@Bind(R.id.restSeekBar)
SeekBar restBar;
@Bind(R.id.applyButton)
Button applyButton;

int maxWork = 60;
int minWork = 5;
int maxRest = 60;
int minRest = 1;

int desiredWorkTime;
int desiredRestTime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_screen);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Boolean isLoggedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("currentUser", false);


    workBar.setMax(maxWork - minWork);
    workBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            desiredWorkTime = minWork + progress;
            work.setText("Current: " + desiredWorkTime + " minutes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    restBar.setMax(maxRest - minRest);
    restBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            desiredRestTime = minRest + progress;
            work.setText("Current: " + desiredRestTime + " minutes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: where you are finding view?

Comment: you use  binding library for binding a view .so check it  i think it give null reference to your views.

Comment: Either your layout doesn't have an element with the name you think it does, or your annotation processing magic is broken.  Of course we can't tell the second because god only knows what those are doing-  it isn't in the code.  That's why those things are a horrible idea.

Comment: @santoXme omg i cant believe i forgot to call "Butterknife.bind(this)". thanks for the help everyone